# Is it true that any group $G$ is isomorphic to a subdirect product of subdirectly irreducible groups?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

We know that any ring is isomorphic to a [subdirect product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subdirect_product) of [subdirectly irreducible rings](https://planetmath.org/SubdirectlyIrreducibleRing).

If $G$ is an additive abelian group then $G$ can easily be considered as a ring by defining multiplication "$\cdot$" on $G$ as the the map $\cdot:G\times G\to G$ defined by $a\cdot b=0_G$ for all $a,b\in G$. Denote this ring on $G$ by $R(G)$. Observe that if $S$ is a subgroup of $G$ then $S$ is an ideal of $R(G)$ and conversely for any ideal $I$ or $(R(G),+,\cdot)$, $(I,+)$ is a subgroup of $(G,+)$. In other words the ideals of $R(G)$ are precisely the subgroups of $G$.

Observe that if $S$ is a subgroup of $G$ then $S$ is an ideal of $R(G)$ and conversely for any ideal $I$ or $(R(G),+,\cdot)$, $(I,+)$ is a subgroup of $(G,+)$. In other words the ideals of $R(G)$ are precisely the subgroups of $G$. From this observation it follows that $G$ is isomorphic to a subdirect product of commutative simple groups. But what about the case when $G$ is not abelian?

**My Attempt**

I was trying to generalize the idea of a ring to an algebraic structure, call it $g$-ring where the underlying additive group need not be abelian. Then I was trying to prove the following theorem,

> Any $g$-ring is isomorphic to a subdirect product of subdirectly irreducible $g$-rings.

But till now I haven't been able to prove anything close to it.

Comment: Any algebra of any type (in the sense of universal algebra) is a subdirect product of subdirectly irreducible algebras. So if your $g$-rings can be described in terms of operations and equations, then the result is true for general reasons

Comment: Does the fact that ["every group is a subgroup of a simple group"](https://mathoverflow.net/q/247402/35478) answer your question?

Comment: Yeah, you can make any finite group $G$ a subgroup of the simple group $A_{2n},$ where $n=|G|.$ Simple groups are not the same as "sub-directly irreducible groups," however. $A_{m}$ is simple for all $m.$

Comment: @Max: I think your comment answers my question very nicely.

Comment: @user1729: Thanks for the link. I wasn't so sure of the result and hence mentioned only simple groups. Needless to say that the post also answers my question.

Comment: I haven't read the body of your post and I am confused by some of the comments because the answer to the question in your title is clearly no. The cyclic group of order four is a counterexample.

Comment: @DerekHolt: I think you are right. I have edited the title accordingly. In fact I was interested in the subdirectly irreducible groups (to which Max's comment answers the question perfectly). Probably the subdirectly irreducible subgroups are minimal subgroups of a group.

Comment: The question would have clearly benefitted of including full definitions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subdirectly_irreducible_algebra) at "Properties", the first sentence is what you're looking for.

For a reference with a proof, you may want to check out Grätzer's *Universal Algebra* , or Burris and Sankappanavar's *A course in universal algebra*. If you want a proof I can write it up here, it's not too complicated.

Added : here's the proof.

It's easy to see that an algebra is subdirectly irreducible if and only if it has a minimum nontrivial congruence (otherwise, if the intersection of all nontrivial congruences is trivial, then this means our algebra embeds into the product of its nontrivial quotients, and this is clearly a subdirect product).

Now let $A$ be an algebra, and for $a\neq b\in A$, $\Psi(a,b)$ a maximal congruence not containing $(a,b)$ (it exists by Zorn's lemma), and $\Theta(a,b)$ the least congruence containing $(a,b)$. Then, finally put $R(a,b)= \Psi(a,b)\vee \Theta(a,b)$ ($\vee$ in the sense of congruences).

Notice that any congruence strictly containing $\Psi(a,b)$ also contains $\Theta(a,b)$ : that is by maximality of $\Psi(a,b)$ and definition of $\Theta(a,b)$. It follows that any congruence strictly containing $\Psi(a,b)$ also contains $R(a,b)$. Therefore by the correspondance theorem, "$R(a,b)$" is the minimum congruence of $A/\Psi(a,b)$ : $A/\Psi(a,b)$ is subdirrectly irreducible.

It just remains to check that $\bigcap_{a\neq b}\Psi(a,b)$ is the trivial congruence, when $A$ is not itself subdirectly irreducible .

If this is true, then $A\to \prod_{a\neq b}A/\Psi(a,b)$ will do the trick (where the indexing set is the same as above).
But well if $a\neq b$, then $(a,b)\notin \Psi(a,b)$, so $(a,b)\notin \bigcap_{c\neq d}\Psi(c,d)$, so the intersection is indeed trivial, and we are done.

Comment: You can write it but I would be glad to chat with you about it if you prefer. In that case please come to [this room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72901/general-chat-with-user-170039).

Comment: I don't think there's that much to discuss so I just added the proof